# Powershell - Download OneDrive files for all users using Graph

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to use Graph to list all users in my M365 tenant, look at a folder within their OneDrive, and then download the contents

Each user has the same folder inside OneDrive "Custom Export",

I am seeing Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. errors when running this script:

```
$ClientId = "xxxxxxx"
$ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxxx"
$TenantId = "xxxxxxxxxx"
$StoragePath = "C:\Export"  # Local storage path

$tokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"
$tokenBody = @{
    client_id     = $ClientId
    scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    client_secret = $ClientSecret
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
}
$tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $tokenUrl -Method Post -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Body $tokenBody
$accessToken = $tokenResponse.access_token

# Set up Graph authentication headers
$graphHeaders = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $accessToken"
}

#Function to download files
function DownloadFile($itemId, $userId, $fileName, $displayName) {
    $downloadUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/$itemId/content"
    Write-Host "Downloading file from: $downloadUrl"

    $fileContent = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $downloadUrl -Headers $graphHeaders -Method Get

    if ($fileContent -and $fileContent.Length -gt 0) {
        $userFolderPath = Join-Path $StoragePath $displayName
        if (-not (Test-Path $userFolderPath)) {
            New-Item -Path $userFolderPath -ItemType Directory
        }

        $downloadPath = Join-Path $userFolderPath $fileName
        [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($downloadPath, $fileContent)
        Write-Host "File downloaded and saved to: $downloadPath"
    } else {
        Write-Host "File content is empty or missing for item ID: $itemId"
    }
}
# Get a list of users
$usersUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"
$usersResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $usersUrl -Headers $graphHeaders
$users = $usersResponse.value

# Loop through users
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $userId = $user.id
    $dname = $display.displayName

    # List files from the root directory of OneDrive
    $listUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$userId/drive/root/children/Custom Export/children"
    $listResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $listUrl -Headers $graphHeaders
    $files = $listResponse.value

    foreach ($file in $files) {
        $itemId = $file.id
        $fileName = $file.name
        $filePath = Join-Path $StoragePath $dname $fileName

        # Create the user's folder if it doesn't exist
        $userFolderPath = Join-Path $StoragePath $userId
        if (-not (Test-Path $userFolderPath)) {
            New-Item -Path $userFolderPath -ItemType Directory
        }

        # Download and save the file
        DownloadFile -itemId $itemId -downloadPath $filePath
    }
}

Write-Host "Script execution completed."
```

The app registration has directory.readwrite, file.readwrite, site.readwrite

I can also browse the contents of the directories using the graph explorer

If I remove the IF condition in the function and change to not check the file content length, this does create the folders but does not download the content of the files

```
function DownloadFile($itemId, $userId, $fileName) {
    $downloadUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/$itemId/content"
    Write-Host "Downloading file from: $downloadUrl"

    $fileContent = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $downloadUrl -Headers $graphHeaders -Method Get

    $userFolderPath = Join-Path $StoragePath $userId
    New-Item -Path $userFolderPath -ItemType Directory -Force

    $downloadPath = Join-Path $userFolderPath $fileName
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($downloadPath, $fileContent)
    Write-Host "File downloaded and saved to: $downloadPath"
}
```